# rich:extendedDataTable in rich:panel is compressed

Tags: jsf, richfaces

I am trying to use an extendedDataTable inside a panel. I am using the following Code:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<ui:composition 
    xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page" 
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
    xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">

    <f:view>
        <h:head></h:head>
        <h:body>
            <h:form id="form">
                <rich:panel style="width:400px">
                    <rich:extendedDataTable 
                          value="#{mitarbeiterBean.mitarbeiter}"
                          var="mitarbeiter"
                          style="width: 100%;">
                        <rich:column sortBy="#{mitarbeiter.vorname}">
                            <f:facet name="header">
                                <h:outputText value="Vorname" />
                            </f:facet>
                            <h:outputText value="#{mitarbeiter.vorname}" />
                        </rich:column>

                        <rich:column sortBy="#{mitarbeiter.nachname}">
                            <f:facet name="header">
                                <h:outputText value="Nachname" />
                            </f:facet>
                            <h:outputText value="#{mitarbeiter.nachname}" />
                        </rich:column>
                    </rich:extendedDataTable>
                </rich:panel>
            </h:form>
        </h:body>
    </f:view>
</ui:composition>
```

The backing bean:

```java
import javax.inject.Named;

@Named
public class MitarbeiterBean {
    public class Mitarbeiter {
        private String vorname;
        private String nachname;

        public Mitarbeiter (String vorname, String nachname) {
            this.vorname= vorname;
            this.nachname= nachname;
        }

        public String getVorname () {
            return vorname;
        }

        public void setVorname (String vorname) {
            this.vorname= vorname;
        }

        public String getNachname () {
            return nachname;
        }

        public void setNachname (String nachname) {
            this.nachname= nachname;
        }
    }

    public Mitarbeiter[] getMitarbeiter () {
        return new Mitarbeiter[] {
            new Mitarbeiter("Hans", "Müller"),
            new Mitarbeiter("Heiri", "Meier"),
            new Mitarbeiter("Max", "Mustermann"),
            new Mitarbeiter("Susi", "Sorgenlos")
        };
    }
}
```

The table doesn't use its space and is compressed to the left. I almost get what I want with the following CSS:

```
.rf-edt-tbl {
    width: 100%;
}

.rf-edt-tbl tr td {
    width: 50%;
}

.rf-edt-tbl tr td div {
    width: auto;
}
```

But when a scrollbar appears, headers and content of the table get out of alignment.

How can I make my table looking right?

Comment: try using outputPanel instead of panel

Comment: Thank you for your comment. What kind of outputPanel do you mean? I tried a4j:outputPanel, but without success. The the panel spans the the whole page breadth, but the table remains compressed.

Comment: have you tried using `style="width:100%"` in your panel? And yes, I've suggested using `a4j:outputPanel`.

Comment: This doesn't help, it only makes the panel spread the whole width, but the table remains compressed.

Comment: This problem sounds a "XHTML+CSS renderization problem", on your program's output. What browser (Firefox? Chorme?) you  use?  What the window width  (ex. a screen of 1024 pixels)?  If is it, please show peaces of the HTML source code.

Answer (score 0):

Use this style in your rich:extendedDataTable tag

```
style="table-layout:fixed;"
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I tried it, but it didn't change anything.

Comment: Ok, I think Usman is in the right way, but we need more clues... See above.

Comment: rich:extendedDataTable have fixed width so we have to set the width according to the situation, remove the rich:panel width . In Your Css remove the this class style ".rf-edt-tbl tr td" please inspect the html source by using the google inspect what is the actual width are having for datatable in browser.

Answer (score -1):

I have this same problem, I'll provide additional information in case it gives some clue:

Each cell has this additional class (might have something to do with the column resizing):

```
.rf-edt-c-j_idt162 {
  width: 100px;
}
```

The numbers after j_idt change for each column. That class is fixing column width, compressing the columns.

It overrides both .rf-edt-c and .rf-edt-hdr-c so I can't set a specific width using those.

`<div class="rf-edt-c rf-edt-c-j_idt162"...`

If I set column width with something like this:

```
.rf-edt TABLE {
   width:100;
}
.rf-edt DIV {
   width: 100%;
}
```

Then columns expand to fill the area, but header and content align wrong, since header and content are in different tables.

Comment: Did I fail to explain it clearly, or is it just that there is nothing that can be done about it?

Comment: Is this an answer? A question? Something else?